# Why this code is not running in emulator even if i have given all the permission in the code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

### TelephonyManagerActivity.java

```
package com.lovepurohit.project15;

/**
* Program for telephony manager that means to access the details related
* to sim and phone number like IMEI number, Device type and many more
* <p/>
* For this we use TelephonyManagerActivity class which is in the package
* android.telephony.TelephonyManagerActivity;
*/


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

//importing our new package
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Created by Love on 04-07-2017.
*/
public class TelephonyManagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager_telephony);

    //Getting id
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    //Accessing the service for performing operation related to telephony
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    /**
     * Getting the phone Type
     * whether phone is cdma or gsm
     */
    int type = tm.getPhoneType();

    //Getting other details like IMEI number and device id and etc
    String IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();

    //getting subscriber ID
    String subscriberID = tm.getDeviceId();

    //Getting Sim serial number
    String SIMSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();

    //Getting network details
    String networkCountryISO = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

    //Getting sim country info
    String SIMCountryISO = tm.getSimCountryIso();

    //Getting the software on which app is running
    String softwareVersion = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();

    //Getting the voice mail number on which app is running
    String voiceMailNumber = tm.getVoiceMailNumber();

    String strPhoneType = "";
    switch (type) {
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
            strPhoneType = "CDMA";
            break;

        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
            strPhoneType = "GSM";
            break;

        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
            strPhoneType = "NONE";
            break;

    }

    boolean isRoaming = tm.isNetworkRoaming();

    String phoneInfo = "Phone Details: \n";
    phoneInfo += "\n IMEI Number: " + IMEINumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n SubscriberID: " + subscriberID;
    phoneInfo += "\n SIM Serial Number: " + SIMSerialNumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n Network Country ISO: " + networkCountryISO;
    phoneInfo += "\n SIMCountryISO: " + SIMCountryISO;
    phoneInfo += "\n SoftwreVersion: " + softwareVersion;
    phoneInfo += "\n VoiceMailNumber: " + voiceMailNumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n Phone Type: " + strPhoneType;
    phoneInfo += "\n Is Roaming? : " + isRoaming;

    textView.setText(phoneInfo);
}
}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lovepurohit.project15">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="adndroid.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Activity 25th our project -->
    <activity android:name=".SharedPreferences">
        <!-- <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> -->
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity 26th of our project -->
    <activity android:name=".InternalStorage">
       <!-- <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> -->
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity 27th of our project -->
    <activity android:name=".TelephonyManagerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Do I have to run it on the real device? I have added all the permission but it is not working in the emulator. And I'm using API 23 that is Marshmallow

Comment: Where is the code for runtime permission for API level 23 ?

Comment: This app won't work on Emulator. Emulator doesn't have a network sim. Try to run it on actual device.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do thing likethis in your onCreateMethod. I am doing it for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE you can do the same thing for READ_PHONE_STATE

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                       //Show Information about why you need the permission
                       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                       builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                       builder.setMessage("We needs storage permission to proceed");
                       builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                           }
                       });
                       builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                       builder.show();
                   } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
                       //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                       // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                       builder.setTitle("Storage Permission");
                       builder.setMessage("We need storage permission.");
                       builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                               sentToSettings = true;
                               Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                               Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                               intent.setData(uri);
                               startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       });
                       builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                       builder.show();
                   } else {
                       //just request the permission
                       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                   }


                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
                   editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,true);
                   editor.commit();




               } else {
                   //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
                  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


//Accessing the service for performing operation related to telephony
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

/**
 * Getting the phone Type
 * whether phone is cdma or gsm
 */
int type = tm.getPhoneType();

//Getting other details like IMEI number and device id and etc
String IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();

//getting subscriber ID
String subscriberID = tm.getDeviceId();

//Getting Sim serial number
String SIMSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();

//Getting network details
String networkCountryISO = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

//Getting sim country info
String SIMCountryISO = tm.getSimCountryIso();

//Getting the software on which app is running
String softwareVersion = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();

//Getting the voice mail number on which app is running
String voiceMailNumber = tm.getVoiceMailNumber();

String strPhoneType = "";
switch (type) {
    case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
        strPhoneType = "CDMA";
        break;

    case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
        strPhoneType = "GSM";
        break;

    case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
        strPhoneType = "NONE";
        break;

}

boolean isRoaming = tm.isNetworkRoaming();



 String phoneInfo = "Phone Details: \n";
    phoneInfo += "\n IMEI Number: " + IMEINumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n SubscriberID: " + subscriberID;
    phoneInfo += "\n SIM Serial Number: " + SIMSerialNumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n Network Country ISO: " + networkCountryISO;
    phoneInfo += "\n SIMCountryISO: " + SIMCountryISO;
    phoneInfo += "\n SoftwreVersion: " + softwareVersion;
    phoneInfo += "\n VoiceMailNumber: " + voiceMailNumber;
    phoneInfo += "\n Phone Type: " + strPhoneType;
    phoneInfo += "\n Is Roaming? : " + isRoaming;

    textView.setText(phoneInfo);
                   }

 @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING) {
           if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              // Do the exact thing as in else condition above
           }
       }
   }



@Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       if (requestCode == EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT) {
           if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               // Do the exact thing as in else condition above
           } else {
               if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                   //Show Information about why you need the permission
                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                   builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                   builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission");
                   builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           dialog.cancel();


                           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);


                       }
                   });
                   builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
                   builder.show();
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to get Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for  runtime permissons for real devices(see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en).
Emulated device haven't got some of things your asking for and might return null, but other things should give you values. For example in my case the emulated device ID return 00000000000 when I run something like:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

DeviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId() ;
String testToastInfo = DeviceId + "\n";

Toast.makeText(this,testToastInfo , duration).show();
```

Hope this help!